# IMacro to navigate a url from excel file

Tags: automation, macros, imacros

I am trying to navigate to a website "google.com" from Excel row 1 col 1 - (where I have www.google.com)

and

I am using this script

```
    VERSION BUILD=8340723 RECORDER=CR
    TAB OPEN
    SET !DATASOURCE e:\circles.xlsx
   'SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 5
    URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
```

but the  tab opens and it does not navigate to the URL

There is no Error given as well

Can you please help..

Sam

Comment: all it says is replaying dfd.iim

Answer (score 0):

```
  VERSION BUILD=8340723 RECORDER=CR
    TAB OPEN
    SET !DATASOURCE circles.csv
    SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
    URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
```

Edit: I edited the code. You have to put circles CSV file in Datasources folder. Look for Datasources folder in iMacros folder. It has to be comma delimited CSV File. XLSX doesn't work.

Comment: Tried that.. Same result.. - just says replaying <my macro>.iim - but new tab opens... Also tried with circles.csv

Comment: 'Code' 'VERSION BUILD=8340723 RECORDER=CR
    TAB OPEN
    SET !DATASOURCE e:\circles.csv
    SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
    URL GOTO={{!COL1}}  'code' ----------- > Worked Thank a ton.. but How to navigate col 1 until null value/No URL comes in?

Comment: Use JavaScript. Or set number of loops to a null value.

Comment: Sorry about the shabby comment.. ( just trying to edit that as Code).. but it did not work..

Comment: Write in original question about what are you trying to do. There are tons of examples imacros and javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imacros+javascript